# understanding how nested functions work in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to understand how nested functions work for example

```
function outer(){
  console.log("Hello from outer function")
  function inner(){
    console.log("Hello from inner function")
  }
}
```

I want to understand what happens when i call outer(), how can i call the inner function, what is the execution context for inner function,

Comment: You have to put `inner()` somewhere in `outer`, to start with

Comment: `inner` will never be executed because you never call it in `outer` and cannot ever be executed unless you expose it in some way from `outer`. Functions really work the same way regardless of where you put them, the only difference is scoping.

Answer (score 2):

As you have not called `inner()` anywhere in the `outer()` function so that is why inner() is not getting called by default.

JavaScript will automatically allocate memory when values are initially declared. There is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) where you can read about memory management in JS

You cannot call `inner()` from outside. Once outer() finishes executing inner() will be garbage collected, since there is no other references to it.

```js
function outer(){
  console.log("Hello from outer function")
  inner();
  function inner(){
    console.log("Hello from inner function")
  }
}

outer();
```

Using a closure way:

```js
function outer() {
  var name = 'StackOverflow';
  function inner() {
    console.log("I am in Inner function at " + name);
  }
  return inner;
}

var outerfunction = outer();
outerfunction();
```

But if you see we are calling inner() in the outer function indirectly.

Comment: I am not asking why inner function is not being called, i know i am not calling it so it won't be executed
what i want to know is what happens when i call outer function, will there be any memory initialization for inner function if yes how can i access it from outside of outer function

Comment: JavaScript will automatically allocate memory when values are initially declared.

Comment: @MukeshKumar you *cannot* call it from outside. Once `outer` finishes executing `inner` will be garbage collected, since there is no other references to it.

Comment: I believe @VLAZ put a perfect reply about why you can not call inner from outside. I have updated the answer with the comment.

Comment: Yes i think @VLAZ is correct and if i want to store the reference for inner function i will have to create a closure on inner function

Comment: closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JS closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time. @MukeshKumar I have updated answer. But if you see we are calling inner() in the outer function indirectly

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this syntax:

```
functionName()();
```

this is syntax happen when a function return another function. like the code blow:

```
function f1(value1) {
    return function f2(value2) {
        return value1 + value2;
    };
}
```

Comment: No dear, he is asking how can he access the inner function from outside of the outer function

Comment: and I answered you can return the function